# php reading csv data into a single line

Tags: php, csv

It's strange PHP Reading my Excel generated CSV file into a single line. Code is:

```
if ($file) {
                while (($line = fgets($file)) !== false) {
                    print '<div>'.$line.'</div>'."<br/>";
                }

            } else {
                // error opening the file.
            }

            fclose($file);
```

**CSV**

```
Name, City
Jon,Paris
Doe,Madrid
```

Comment: You can try my CSV parser (special for big data and line by line): https://github.com/DeepVarvar/PHP-CSV-Parser-Writer/blob/master/examples/parse-from-file-with-complete-options.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this code before reading the file.

```
ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true);
```

> When turned on, PHP will examine the data read by fgets() and file() to see if it is using Unix, MS-Dos or Macintosh line-ending conventions.

This enables PHP to interoperate with Macintosh systems, but defaults to Off, as there is a very small performance penalty when detecting the EOL conventions for the first line, and also because people using carriage-returns as item separators under Unix systems would experience non-backwards-compatible behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, PHP is not correctly detecting the line endings in your file. The [fgets](http://php.net/fgets) documentation points this out.

You will probably want to write code like this:

```
$oldLineEndings = ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true);

//your while loop here

ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', $oldLineEndings);
```

If you need to actually parse the csv, you may also want to look at [fgetcsv](http://php.net/fgetcsv).